# Is there a significantly different number of people between groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test

How do I estimate whether a given number of people across groups (say, 72 people in group 1, 95 in group 2 and 70 in group 3) significantly differs from a random distribution of people across groups? That is, which statistical test do I have to apply?

Comment: What distribution do you expect the numbers to follow across the groups, the uniform? You should look into this chi-squared test..

Comment: a uniform distribution; many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, you wanted to know if the numbers in the three groups were distributed uniformly (i.e., if the numbers were approximately equal), you can use the $\chi^2$ [goodness of fit test](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/chigf.htm).  You just stipulate that you are assessing the goodness of the fit of your data to a uniform.  Here is a simple example in R:

```r
x = c(72, 95, 70)
chisq.test(x, p=c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x
X-squared = 4.8861, df = 2, p-value = 0.0869
```